# Returning all data in single query without while statement php

Tags: php, mysql

how to get all data in single array 
without using while statement.
here is some code but its not working good..
 any idea about whole query result in sigle assoc array.. any idea??

```
$data=array();
$sql = "SELECT `Name`, `Title`, `Version`, `Date`, `Cover`, `Content` FROM dict";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($data[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
$data[]=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
print_r($data);
```

Comment: What is not working good? Alternatively you can wrap it into a function of it's own and return the whole array or switch to some other database access library like PDO that supports such an operation out of the box.

Comment: its returning such output while i have only 2 records <br>

Array ( [0] => Array ( [Name] => Test [Title] => Test [Version] => 4 [Date] => 2012:01:29 12:25:44 [Cover] => localhost/mag/uploaded/imagesmagazine-4.jpg [Content] => localhost/mag/uploaded/pdfmagazine-4.pdf ) [1] => Array ( [Name] => Test [Title] => Test [Version] => 4 [Date] => 2012:01:29 12:25:44 [Cover] => localhost/mag/uploaded/imagesmagazine-4.jpg [Content] => localhost/mag/uploaded/pdfmagazine-4.pdf ) [2] => )

Comment: You fetch two rows per while iteration. And the last elment  of `$data` will be `FALSE`. See the answers and how they do it differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap it into a function of it's own (and correct the error) so you can't mis-type it any longer:

```
mysql_fetch_assoc_all($result)
{
    $data = array();
    while  ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Usage:

```
$sql = "SELECT `Name`, `Title`, `Version`, `Date`, `Cover`, `Content` FROM dict";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$data = mysql_fetch_assoc_all($result);
```

Take care that `$result` must be a valid result.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it's not working is how you do your loop.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $data[] = $row;
}
```

Then you have an array of associative arrays in `$data`.

I'm not aware of any "single-line" solution. Although you can of course wrap all this in a function as hakre suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit late, but "single line" could be:

```
while($data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));
```